# NServiceBus 4 release date

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus4

I read about a great NSB4 feature to store raw XML files in a messages.
When is NSB4 released and what other features are in the pipeline?

Comment: need 1500 rep's to create NServiceBus4 tag.

Comment: I don't think it would be a good idea to create a separate tag. Most of us troll the NServiceBus tag when looking for people who need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Udi Dahan Edit] We have just put out a release candidate for NServiceBus v4 on [particular.net](http://particular.net). You can check out our release notes [here](http://particular.net/blog/nservicebus-v4.0-release-notes). [End Edit]

I can't speak for the NServiceBus Team, but the power of open source software is on your side here: [NServiceBus Milestones on GitHub](https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/issues/milestones)

At the time I write this, 4.0.0 is due in 20 days, and 95% of issues are complete. (13 open, 252 closed.)

I'm sure the team will want to stabilize for awhile before declaring an RTM.

As for the other features in the pipeline, you can [browse through the 4.0 features](https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/issues?milestone=26) or check out the [more generalized roadmap](http://nservicebus.com/roadmap.aspx).

Comment: you are completely right that I need to build my open source/github skills